# Binomial probability test questions!!

Tags: probability

A baseball player's batting average is 0.310. If a given game he bats four times, what is the probability that he will get:

a) 4 hits?

b) at most one hit?

c) at least one?

My thoughts:

a) 4P1 x (.310)^1 x (1-0.310)^3 + ... + 4P4 x (0.310)^4 x (1-0310)^0

b) 4P1 x (0,310)^1 x (1-0.310)^3

c) is c) the same as a)

Comment: Maybe you should think about the answers to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445174/binomial-probability-question), as this works about the same way.  Then if you are still stuck, ask again.

Answer (score 2):

$(a)\quad$ The probability of obtaining a hit when batting *once* is $0.31$. So the probability of obtaining $4$ hits when batting $4$ *times* is

> $$(a)\quad \,(0.31)\times (0.31)\times (0.31) \times (0.31) = (0.31)^4$$

$(b)\quad$ The probability of making *at most one* hit is the probability of obtaining (exactly one hit) OR (no hits). Let's see what this means, in terms of outcomes:

`hit not not not` Probability: $\quad  (0.31)(1 - 0.31)(1 - 0.31)(1 - 0.31) = (0.31)(1 - 0.31)^3$
`not hit not not` Probability: $\quad  (0.31)(1 - 0.31)^3$ 
`not not hit not` Probability: $\quad  (0.31)(1 - 0.31)^3$
`not not not hit` Probability: $\quad  (0.31)(1 - 0.31)^3$
`not not not not` Probability: $\quad (0.31)^4$

Probability of obtaining at most one hit: we add each of the above

> $$(b)\quad 4\cdot (0.31)(1-0.31)^3 + (0.31)^4 = 4\cdot(0.31)(0.69)^3 + (0.31)^4$$

$(c)$ This is **not** the same as $(a)$. We compute the probability of getting **no hits**, and subtract from $1$ this probability of getting no hits. That difference will give us the probability of getting *at least one* hit.

Probability of getting **no hits** $= (1 - 0.31)^4 = (0.69)^4$.

> (c) So the probability of getting **at least one hit** is equal to $\;1 - \left((0.69)^4\right)$

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti! Sometimes students want to "throw formulas" at a problem without understanding what they're even working with! However, I think the post has been abandoned by the OP. :-/

Comment: +1 but I hate Statistics

Comment: Hehehehe. (Thanks! @Babak) But probability can be fun? ;-)

Comment: Yes maybe in gambling, you're right. ;-)